# What is the shortest way of getting localized name of builtin Windows user account?

Tags: windows, security, delphi, winapi

I need to call `CreateProcessWithLogonW`, for which I need to pass builtin account name (say Administrator). The problem is that builtin account names are localized. For example in French its "Administrat*eur*" and when I pass "Administrator" to the function, it returns `ERROR_LOGON_FAILURE`.

In order to get a builtin account name, I can pass its SID to `LookupAccountBySid`. Pretty easy. The problem is that, according to [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/243330/well-known-security-identifiers-in-windows-operating-systems), the SID I need to pass is following:

**S-1-5-21domain-500**

How do I get the domain part?

I found [this code](https://delphi-kb.blogspot.com/2012/11/get-current-users-sid.html), but in order to get current user's SID (from where I could get the domain part), it calls chain of functions including `OpenProcessToken, GetTokenInformation, HeapAlloc, GetSidIdentifierAuthority, GetSidSubAuthorityCount, GetSidSubAuthority`...

This would be rather insane for getting simple domain string. Is there a shorter way to do this?

Comment: Interesting question, why do you need CreateProcessWithLogonW instead of standard elevation? Multiple problems arise with your approach, what if the standard domain administrator account is disabled? Are you expecting the user to enter the domain administrator password? etc...

Comment: Anyway, take a look [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/157234/how-to-deal-with-localized-and-renamed-user-and-group-names). DOMAIN_USER_RID_ADMIN seems what you are looking after...

Comment: @whosrdaddy I just came across CreateProcessWithLogonW function and started to write code around it. What I need to do is to be able to run a process as different user. What is the "standard elevation" approach?

Comment: Hi mark, never mind, elevation (UAC) only works from the same process so CreateProcessWithLogonW would be a correct alternative. Did you take a look at he link?

Comment: get this admin name not hard, but you anyway don know password for this account and account can be disabled

Comment: @whosrdaddy code under link very bad and not efficient. need use `LsaOpenPolicy` + `LsaQueryInformationPolicy` with `PolicyAccountDomainInformation` + `CreateWellKnownSid` with `WinAccountAdministratorSid` + `LsaLookupSids`

Comment: @mark Has this issue solved?